# Directory.CreateDirectory(Path) does not create the given folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

This code is running in a ASP Page.

```
    try 
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(destDir);
        DirectoryInfo diOut = Directory.CreateDirectory(destDir + "\\output");

        if (di.Exists) 
        {
            ErrorLog(Server.MapPath("Logs/ErrorLog"),"created or existing destDir: " + destDir );
        } 

        if (diOut.Exists) 
        {
           ErrorLog(Server.MapPath("Logs/ErrorLog"),"created or existing outputDir:" + destDir +"\\output" );
        }

    } 
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        ErrorLog(Server.MapPath("Logs/ErrorLog"),"caught error: " + e.ToString() );
    }
```

The value of dst dir is:

> d:\foo-server\THE\jobgenerator\xmlinput\tmp_JobGenerator_09_08_201216_09_21_718374_THE

The parent folder `d:\foo-server\THE\jobgenerator\xmlinput` already exists.

The log output says that the destDir has been created but when I check the folder I can see that there has been nothing created. The Site is running on a IIS, the configured user has full permission on the parent folder.

I dont understand why the di.Exists results in true even if the folder has not been created. Also no Exception will be thrown.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Probably not a solution, but instead of concatenating the strings together to get a path, you should best use `Path.Combine`.

Comment: What is the destination directory variable set to ?

Comment: destDir=d:\foo-server\THE\jobgenerator\xmlinput\tmp_JobGenerator_09_08_201216_09_21_718374_THE

Comment: @dotTutorials:- The value of dst dir is :d:\foo-server\THE\jobgenerator\xmlinput\tmp_JobGenerator_09_08_201216_09_21_718374_THE

Comment: C# is not the same as ASP Classic.  Edited to ASP.NET

Comment: try ErrorLog(Server.MapPath("Logs/ErrorLog"),"created or existing destDir: " + di.FullName); and check where are they created...

Comment: For debugging purposes use Directory.Exists and see if the result is the same.

Comment: di.Fullname returns the same path "created or existing destDir: d:\foo-server\THE\jobgenerator\xmlinput\tmp_JobGenerator_09_08_201216_42_48_414459_THE" and Directory.Exists returns also true

Comment: Are you expecting the folder to exist on the server or the client machine?  I know your path has server in it, but the only thing I have left to offer is the code above will create this on whatever d: is on the IIS server.  I have never seen Directory.Exists to return true for a directory that doesn't exist, so I'm hoping in the confusion you're visually inspecting an improper location for the folder.

Comment: I am also confused, why the function returns true. The page should create this directory on the server where the iis is located. The parent folder exists, but it does not create the given subfolder. I was expecting an exception, but without it I dont understand what happens

Comment: Have you tried giving sysname\iis_wpg permission to the folder?

Comment: I gave the IUSR permission to the folder, also I used an extra user for the page which had all the permission. I dont think that the permissions are the problem. Because I tried to create some test folder which worked, maybe the path of destdir is invalid?

Comment: does anyone has an idea? Its really strange, i can create a directory if i define the path directly DirectoryInfo di2 = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\foo-server\THE\jobgenerator\xmlinput\foo" ); but the creation of the folder from the destDir Variable does not work

Comment: Probably `destDir` is not what you think it is. Try hard coding its value e.g. `destDir = @"d:\foo-server\THE\jobgenerator\xmlinput\tmp_JobGenerator_09_08_201216_09_21_718374_THE";` and see what happens.